# Permission denied when trying to run karaf 0.8.1

Tags: opendaylight

I downloaded the OpenDaylight Oxygen SR1 Zip file, unzipped the karaf-0.8.1 file, changed my directory to it but when I try to run `./bin/karaf` I get:

> ./bin/karaf: Permission denied

When I try `sudo ./bin/karaf` I get

> sudo: ./bin/karaf: command not found

The weirdest part is that I also have the folder of the previous version, i.e. karaf-0.7.1, in the same Downloads folder and these commands work perfectly fine in there. I would like to use the latest version however. Could anyone help me please?

**Edit**: Sorry, forgot to mention I'm running it on Mac OS X

Comment: you should NEVER use sudo to run something like Karaf as root... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a Unix-like system, you’re better off downloading [the tarball](https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/org/opendaylight/integration/karaf/0.8.1/karaf-0.8.1.tar.gz): extracting that will give you files with the correct permissions.

In your case, to fix your setup, you need to run

```
chmod 755 bin/{client,inc,instance,karaf,setenv,set_persistence.sh,shell,start,status,stop}
```

to restore the permissions as they ship in the tarball.